# Why isn't $A''=A'$? and $(A\cap B)'=A'\cap B'$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have managed to show that the set of limit points of $A'$ is a subset of $A'$ but the opposite is not true, I was wondering why aren't the set of limit points of $A$ and set of limit points of $A'$ are equal? Moreover, it is easy to show that $(A\cap B)'\subseteq A'\cap B'$ but I am unable to show the converse of this and I am not sure if the converse acutally holds or not.

**Definition** :

1. $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$.
2. $A''$ is the set of limit points of $A'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the set $A=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$: $A'=\{0\}$, and $A''=\varnothing$. This is what happens when a limit point of a set is a limit **only** of isolated points, not of other limit points.

It’s not necessarily true that $A'\cap B'\subseteq(A\cap B)'$: take $A$ as above, and let $B=\{0\}\cup\left\{-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.